# how to give random time interval in images in android

Tags: android

In my app, animated image should repeat every time with different time interval.
like i want any of between 1000 to 5000.
I applied below code but this not work properly. Image move very fast. 
So, plz help me out of this problem.

```
       Random gen = new Random();
       anim.setDuration(new Random().nextInt(5000-1000+1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to set [interpolator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html).

```
anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
```

So its speed will be proportioned

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you even didn't check values returned by nextInt(5000-1000+1).If you check this you will discover that values are from 0 to 4001.

If you need values from 1000 to 5000 use:

```
anim.setDuration(1000 + gen.nextInt(4000));
```